# Decoding bit sequence by iterating a tree

Tags: python, tree, huffman-code

```
phrase='hello overflow'
sequence='00100011101010000110101011000110110100'
tree=[
       [
         [
           [' ', 'f'],
           ['h', 'r']
         ],
         [
           ['w', 'v'],
           'e'
         ]
       ],
       ['l', 'o']
     ]
```

I'm having a bit of a problem doing the iteration of the list "tree". What I want to do is, given an input stream of bits, "sequence" in this case, "tree" is iterated accordingly to each bit, for example:

If I want the letter 'h', in "phrase", wich corresponds to the 4 first bits in "sequence", (0010), I must go to tree[0][0][1][0].

I have 2 ideas on how to do this, one of them is by using a for loop like this:

```
for bit in phrase:
    if len(tree[bit])>1:
        calls recursive method, plus some rules

def recursive(list,bit):
    return list[bit]
```

But this gives me a problem, as I cannot feed new bits from the stream, while inside the loop from the recursive method.

The other is by using some sort of parallel iteration between "sequence" and "tree".

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You can access the iterator protocol directly. Just have an infinite loop surrounded by the appropriate `try/except` block, and call `next` when *you* need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion.  Just loop over the bits in the sequence.  Start with `pos = tree`.  For each bit, move down the tree: `pos = pos[bit]`.  If `pos` is still a list, continue with the next bit.  If `pos` is not a list, then output the character there and set `pos` back to the root `tree` and continue with the next bit.  If you leave the loop with `pos` not equal to `tree`, then note an error that you received an incomplete code.

Comment: Thank you, I knew was something simple, feel so dumb. By the way `pos=tree[bit]` must be `pos=pos[int(bit)]` otherwise, it'll just be iterating at the first level of the tree. Did it like this:

`pos=tree`
`for bit in sequence:`
`    pos=pos[int(bit)]`
`    if type(pos).__name__=='str':`
`        print pos`
`        pos=tree`

Sorry dont know how to format properly.